# Yii2 do not see post fields

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I've created a simple rest controller with action, and trying to send post data via restclient mozilla extension. There is a problem, yii2 don't see all post fields and $_POST is []. Request method is POST and I am sending data for sure.

[image]

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }


    public function actionAuth() {
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost) {

            $username = Yii::$app->request->post('username');
            $password = Yii::$app->request->post('password');

            $user = Players::find()
                ->where(['username' => $username])
                ->orWhere(['email' => $username])
                ->one();

            if($user->validatePassword($password)) {
                $user->generateApiToken();
                $user->save();
                return ['status' => 'ok', 'message' => Yii::t('api', 'You are logged in successfully!'), 'data' => $user];
            } else {
                return ['status' => 'error', 'message' => Yii::t('api', 'Username or password is wrong.'), 'post' => $_POST];
            }
        }



        else return ['status' => 'error'];
    }
}
```

Comment: _“and trying to send post data via restclient mozilla extension”_ - show us what exactly you are sending then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Use postman or another software which allow you to send form-data. Not only raw body/

Answer (score 0):

Did't you missed the (`'post' => $_POST`) argument of your if?

try this:

```
return ['status' => 'ok', 'message' => Yii::t('api', 'You are logged in successfully!'), 'data' => $user, 'post' => $_POST];
```

Comment: No, if auth is successfull it means post working correct. In every request post is empty and becouse of that auth is always incorrect.